# Executing Multiple MySQL Queries in a PHP/HTML Webpage: only first query runs

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a webpage written in HTML. I have a dropdown list that is populated by a database utilizing a MySQL query:

```
<SELECT NAME = "Participant" STYLE = "WIDTH: 187" TITLE="Begin typing participant last name for fast searching." required>
<OPTION SELECTED VALUE = "">Select Participant...</OPTION>
<?PHP
    $allParticipants = getall_participants();
    foreach($allParticipants as &$value) {
        $dt = date('Y-m-d'); 
        $val = $value->get_id();
        $optval = $dt.$val;
        echo "<OPTION VALUE='",$optval,"'>";
        echo $value->get_first_name()," ",$value->get_last_name();
        echo "</OPTION>";
    }
?>
</SELECT>
```

The getall_participants() looks like:

```
function getall_participants () {
connect();
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbParticipants ORDER BY last_name";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$theParticipant = array();
while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $theParticipant = new Participant($result_row['last_name'], 
                      $result_row['first_name'], $result_row['address']);
    $theParticipants[] = $theParticipant;
}
mysql_close();
return $theParticipants;
}
```

And on this same page I have a textbox that is pre-filled-in by another database:

```
<?php
    $dt = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $participants = getall_dbParticipantEntry_byDate($dt);
    foreach($participants as &$value) {
        $a = $a.$value.", ";
    }
    echo "<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='Participants' STYLE='WIDTH:50px;' TITLE='Participants' ";
    echo "VALUE='[", $a.' ', "]'/>";
?>
```

That getall_dbParticipantEntry_byDate($date) looks like:

```
function getall_dbParticipantEntry_byDate($date) {
connect();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dbParticipantEntry WHERE date = "'.$date.'"';
$result = mysql_query ($query);
$theParticipantEntry = array();
while ($result_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $theParticipantEntry = new ParticipantEntry($result_row['date'], $result_row['id'], $result_row['call_time'],
    $result_row['result'], $result_row['notes']);
    $theParticipantEntries[] = $theParticipantEntry->get_id();
}
mysql_close();
return $theParticipantEntries;
}
```

However, while both of these functions work fine individually, when they're both on the same webpage (like I meant them to be), only the one that comes first runs. I tested this by switching them in and out. They both complete their designated tasks, but only when alone on the page.
How can I get them both to run and populate their respective fields?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following order:

1. Connect to mySQL server
2. Do task 1
3. Do task 2
4. Close Connection

For me it looks, like you have closed the mysqlconnection, before you do task2.

Edit:

Maybe you can do it like that?

```
function f1 ()
{
    $res = mysql_connect(...);

    // .. do some queries ..
    mysql_query($sql, $res); 

    mysql_close($res ) 
}

function f2 ()
{
    $res = mysql_connect(...);

    // .. do some queries ..
    mysql_query($sql, $res); 

    mysql_close($res ) 
}
```

Edit:

From php.net:

Be careful when using multiple links to connect to same database (with same username). Unless you specify explicitly in mysql_connect() to create a new link, it will return an already open link. If that would be closed by mysql_close(), it will also (obviously) close the other connection, since the link is the same.
Had lot of trouble figuring it out, since in <=4.3.6 there was a bug which didn't close the connection, but after the patch to >=4.3.7, all my application broke down because of a single script that did this.

Comment: I do close the connection, but then I reconnect in the next function. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Via the "connect();" in the PHP. Doesn't that reconnect to the database?

Comment: Yes, that resolved the issue...I do wish there were another way around having to remove the mysql_close();
Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You run them both on the same connection. You need to store the resource id returned from mysql_connect and pass this to each mysql method (each uses it's own relevant resource).

that said, I think it is time to:

1. Move to something more modern like Mysqli or PDO extensions. Much better API
2. Use some kind of abstraction on the connection managment, preferably one instance of a DB managment class per connection. Plenty of examples on the web, and it is way above the scope of this site to provide such instructions.